# Unable to read from file after 1 test run, org.apache.poi.EmptyFileException: The supplied file was empty (zero bytes long)

Tags: java, file, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am attaching the code. Basically what happens is that the first test run goes ok, however in the second test run the file gets corrupted somehow.

```
File src=new File("C:\\Users\\Sajid\\Desktop\\SeleniumData.xlsx");   
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
sheet= workbook.getSheetAt(0);

for(int i=1; i<=sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++){
// Import data for Email.
cell = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(0);
cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
new WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"email\"]")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"email\"]")).sendKeys(cell.getStringCellValue());
Thread.sleep(500);
// Import data for password.
cell = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(1);
cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"password\"]"));
Actions act1 = new Actions(driver);
act1.moveToElement(password).perform();
password.clear();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"password\"]")).clear();          
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"password\"]")).sendKeys(cell.getStringCellValue());
Thread.sleep(500);
// To click on Login button
driver.findElement(By.className("submit")).click();
Thread.sleep(4000);
FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(src);
// Message to be written in the excel sheet
WebElement ele4 = driver.findElement(By.className("mdi-settings"));
act1.moveToElement(ele4).perform();
driver.findElement(By.className("mdi-settings")).click();
Thread.sleep(1000);
WebElement ele5 = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Location Details"));
act1.moveToElement(ele5).perform();
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Location Details")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
cell = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(2);
cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id =\"name\"]")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id =\"name\"]")).sendKeys(cell.getStringCellValue());
fos.close();
fis.close();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("b.hidden-xs")).click();
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.sign-out")).click();
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

The exception that i am getting at the second iteration is:

> org.apache.poi.EmptyFileException: The supplied file was empty (zero
>   bytes long)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in `FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(src);`, it creates new file without content. Since `src` is the input file as well its now empty.

Either don't use it (I couldn't find any uses), write to another file or use `FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(src, true);` if you want to append data to the file.